Adding Emojis to python Reportlab pdf
I am dynamically generating pdf files. My text has emojis but I can't seem to correctly display them. I tried using Symbola font it worked but some of the emojis are missing and the emojis are black and white. Is there a way to add the emojis in color using the apple emojis? I am generating the pdf using python and reportlab

is there a reason not to use the method on top of the Google search results ?

The link isn't accessible

Symbola is not an emoji font. It does contain some characters that are considered emoji, but will dislplay them as their text presentations rather than their emoji representations.
